# Showing $x\to cx+b$ is a ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

In the book *Algebra* by Hungerford, at page 167, at question 14, it is asked that

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity, and $c,b \in R$ with $c$
>   is unit.Show that the assignment $x \to cx + b$ is a unique
>   automorphism of $R[x]$ that is the identity map on $R$.

However, consider $R = \mathbb{Z}$, $c = 1$, $b = 2$. Then since this assignment is a homomorphism, it must be true that 
$$x(x+1) \to x^2 + x + 2 = (x+1)(x+3) = x^2 + 4x + 3,$$
which is clearly not true.Therefore, considering the fact that [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201573/structure-of-textaut-rrx) is even asked in math overflow, and got answer, what is wrong in my argument ?

Comment: In the first part, doesn't $x(x+1)$ map to $(x+2)(x+3)$?

Comment: @Randall $x(x+1) = x^2 + x \to x^2 + x + 2$; $c=1$ and $b = 2$, so we just add $2$ to every polynomial.

Comment: Not so.  You're not applying the transformation to each individual $x$, and you should be.

Comment: @Randall So the map on $R[x]$ is actually $f(x) \to  f(cx+b)$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's what he said:  replace $x$ by $cx+b$.

Comment: Note that he is not defining the auto on ALL of the polynomial ring, just on its action by $x$.  But this then dictates the entire thing by linearity and distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is fine.  You are transforming by $x \mapsto x+2$ and extending by linearity and distribution.  Call the resulting map $\phi: \mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{Z}[x]$.

With your example you have
$$
\phi(x(x+1)) = \phi(x^2+x) = (x+2)^2+(x+2)= x^2+5x+6.
$$
On the other hand,
$$
\phi(x)\phi(x+1)= (x+2)(x+3) = x^2+5x+6
$$
so yes, they are equal.

Answer (score 2):

.You should try to prove that $\phi(x)\phi(x+1) = \phi(x(x+1))$.

Note that $\phi(x) = x+2$, $\phi(x+1) = x+3$, and their product is $x^2+5x+6$.

Next, $x(x+1) = x^2+x$, and $\phi(x^2+x) = (x+2)^2 + x+2 = x^2+4x+4+x+2 = x^2+5x+6$.

---

What you did, instead, was find $x \times x+1$, and compare this with $\phi(x) \times \phi(x+1)$ (which was also computed wrongly).

Note that $x \to cx+b$ means that for each $f \in R[x]$ we have $f(x) \to f(cx+b)$. In other words, $f$ is sent to $g$, the polynomial formed by substituting every occurence of $x$ in $f$, by $cx+b$.

The other way of saying this, is that any homomorphism from $R[x] \to R[x]$ which is the identity on $R$,  is specified uniquely by where $x$ goes, because of the above correspondence.